# Cómo devolver el resultado de una consulta en SQLite en un label en C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

lo que quiero hacer es que a través de una consulta en sqlite el valor me lo devuelva en un label que se encuentra en la interfaz ya he intentado varias cosas sin éxito y necesito ayuda.

por ahora este es todo el codigo de la barra de busqueda aunque no tiene todo ya que he quitado las partes que no me servian para lo que quiero

```
try
        {
            string quer = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE nombreProducto LIKE 'd%';";
            SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = StoreDB.db; Version = 3; New = False; Compress = True;");
            conexion.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(quer, conexion);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@val", buscador.Text));
            SQLiteDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (result.HasRows)
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    artic1.Text = result.GetValue();
                }
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

[image: aqui se puede apreciar lo que trato de hacer]

Comment: Comparte el código que has intentado para tener un punto desde el cual poder empezar. He de suponer que has conseguido que la BD te devuelva los datos y tu problema es que no sabes como mapear esos registros al label?

Comment: Si muestras un poco de tu código ayudaría a darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: bueno editaré la publicación original aunque no me imaginé que fuera necesario ya que lo que busco es algo simple (pero que no se hacer) lo único que he logrado hacer es guardar datos pero ahora quiero una forma de mostrarlos

Comment: A ver si pillo la idea. Tu escribes el nombre del articulo en tu TextBox(Buscador) esto lanza un evento(supongo ya, que no veo ningun boton buscar) de llamada a SQLite.Una vez mapeada la variable (artic1) ¿que haces con ella? ¿Es un textbox?¿Si es un textbox lo insertas en tu panel de resultados(label2,3,4,5 ..etc)?

Comment: estas en lo cierto pero artic1 es un label y quiero que su texto cambie al valor del registro de la tabla sql, por ejemplo la flecha que dice articulo apuntando a un label es ese label el que debe cambiar su texto de acuerdo a la busqueda realizada por ejem si yo busco :"d" los label deben cambiar el texto a resultados similares que esten en la table del sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlLite te está devolviendo los valores en DataReader (result) que estás recorriendo dentro de tu while (result.Read()).

Ahora bien, como el DataReader debe contener varias columnas, debes indicar cuál es la que te interesa recuperar, ya sea indicando la posición de la columna que quieres recuperar (como en el siguiente código modificado), o con el nombre

```
try
    {
        string quer = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE nombreProducto LIKE 'd%';";
        SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = StoreDB.db; Version = 3; New = False; Compress = True;");
        conexion.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(quer, conexion);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@val", buscador.Text));
        SQLiteDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (result.HasRows)
        {
            while (result.Read())
            {
                artic1.Text = result[0].ToString(); //Acá recuperamos el valor de la primera columna y lo mostramos en artic1.
            }
        }
        conexion.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
```

Sin embargo, el código anterior todavía tiene un problema:

Como pueden venir varios registros, y estás actualizando el contenido del Label dentro del while, siempre se reemplazará el contenido del último registro y será el único que se vea...

Si quieres ver todos  los datos, tendría que ser algo como lo siguiente:

```
    try
    {
        string quer = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE nombreProducto LIKE 'd%';";
        SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = StoreDB.db; Version = 3; New = False; Compress = True;");
        conexion.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(quer, conexion);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@val", buscador.Text));
        SQLiteDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (result.HasRows)
        {
            while (result.Read())
            {
                artic1.Text += result[0].ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine; //Acá recuperamos el valor de la primera columna y lo vamos concatenando en artic1.
            }
        }
        conexion.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
```

Asumo que artic1 es multilínea...
Si lo que te interesa es otra columna, solo tendrás que indicar el nombre de la columna o bien su posición (cuidado con los tipos).

Ahora bien, en estos casos, el uso de Labels no necesariamente es la mejor alternativa para mostrar una lista de datos. Puedes utilizar un DataGridView o un ListBox.

El siguiente código muestra la solución utilizando un ListBox. Asumiendo que agregaste un ListBox a tu Form con el nombre ***productoListBox***.

```
try
{
    string quer = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE nombreProducto LIKE 'd%';";
    SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = StoreDB.db; Version = 3; New = False; Compress = True;");
    conexion.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(quer, conexion);
    //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@val", buscador.Text));
    SQLiteDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (result.HasRows)
    {
        productoListBox.Items.Clear(); //Eliminamos resultados previos si hubiera.
        while (result.Read())
        {
            productoListBox.Items.Add(result[0].ToString()); //Acá recuperamos el valor de la primera columna y lo agregamos al ListBox.
        }
    }
    conexion.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
```

Comment: ahora solo imprime el numero 1 debajo del label jaja bueno creo que mejor buscare una mejor manera de hacer esto, sabes cual seria la forma mas eficiente de mostrar articulos de de la tabla inventario para este punto de venta?

Comment: ¿Y el resultado contiene varios registros?¿Te aseguraste que el Label sea multilínea? Si utilizas Windows Forms(tienes que indicarlo en tu pregunta), puedes utilizar el control DataGridView, lo que te podría facilitar el llenado del mismo...

Comment: si, es windows forms y trato de devolver todos los registros que coincidan pero que no los devuelva en un solo label sino en varios que están en la interfaz como se ven en la imagen

Comment: Ok. Entonces si bien lo puedes poner en una serie de Labels, tendrías que resolver otros temas; por ejemplo ¿cuántas Labels vas a necesitar? ¿Las agregas dinámicamente? En definitiva, recomiendo utilizar otro control más adecuado (DataGridView si quieres mostrar varias columnas o un ListBox si solo quieres mostrar una). Actualizo la respuesta con un ListBox....